# Excel how many rows contain variable data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to create a formula that would do the following?

`for each unique value in column x, count total occurrences of that value`

and then present something like the image below?
[image]

It would fill out a new column (from `Col F` onwards) for all the different values in `Col A`, it's possible there will be more or less variables.

I am currently using the following to display it inline:

`=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)/2),"")`

however I'd much prefer it to be formatted as the image above describes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the data (or better yet, turn it into a table with Insert > Table), then click Insert > Pivot table.

In the PivotTable Fields pane, drag Title a to the Columns, then again to the Values area.

If you don't like seeing "Count of Title a" in the pivot table, click the dop-arrow next to "Count of Title a" in the Values panel, select "Value Field Settings" and enter a custom name "Count".

[image]

If you have turned the original data into a table before creating the pivot, you can now enter additional data into the next rows. Then go back to the pivot table and refresh it to show the new data.

Comment: Perfect! would it be possible to apply a calculation to the results? I'd like to divide them in half, but unable to by the usual function

Comment: just use a formula below the pivot table `=B5/2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pivot table for achieving this.

Go to Insert -> Pivot -> Select the Column which needs to be Grouped and then Choose Rows and Values to get the count of the rows.